# How can i iterate through a given list and use the same word multiple times using a recursive function

Tags: python, recursion

Here is my code :

```
def count_construct(target, word_bank): 
    def helper(index, current):
        if current == target:
            return 1
        if len(current) > len(target):
            return 0
        if index >= len(word_bank):
            return 0

        count_with_current = helper(index, current + word_bank[index])
        count_without_current = helper(index + 1, current)

        return count_with_current + count_without_current

    return helper(0, '')
```

Now this function helps me form a given target word using the given list which contains random characters and words. now when I run this specific example the code gives me the wrong output because it simply don't use the same word more than once
the example :

```
target_example = "purple"
word_bank_example = ["purp", "p", "ur", "le", "purpl"]
```

The correct output must be 2 but I am getting 1.
The output that my code refuses to reach is this case : `p+ur+p+le`

Can someone explain to me what changes can I make in order for this code to function correctly?

no matter what I try to do I always think of loops but I cant use them in my case

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure your code is doing what you think it does?
you should keep track of your current solution:

```
def count_construct(target, word_bank):
    count = 0
    def helper(current=[]):
        nonlocal count
        current_str = ''.join(current)
        if current_str == target:
            print(f'Found solution: {current}')
            current.pop()
            count += 1
            return

        for w in word_bank:
            if target[len(current_str):].startswith(w):
                current.append(w)
                helper(current)
        if current:
            current.pop()

    helper()
    return count

target_example = "purple"
word_bank_example = ["purp", "pur", "p", "pu", "ur", "le", "purpl", "l", "e"]

print(count_construct(target_example, word_bank_example))
```

Edit: using `pop` instead of clearing the list to find all possible combinations

Output:

```
Found solution: ['purp', 'le']
Found solution: ['purp', 'l', 'e']
Found solution: ['pur', 'p', 'le']
Found solution: ['pur', 'p', 'l', 'e']
Found solution: ['p', 'ur', 'p', 'le']
Found solution: ['p', 'ur', 'p', 'l', 'e']
Found solution: ['purpl', 'e']
7 # returned value
```